# Formatting poetry books

Tags: poetry, publishing

In a book of poetry, should there be uniformity throughout the book in its format? Should every poem be formatted the same way? Can a few poems have hanging indents while others a regular margin?

For eg:
Can two poems in the same book be formatted in two different ways as below:

```
Poem 1:

Your breath has time to straighten,
    Your brain to bubble cool, 
Deals one imperial thunderbolt
    That scalps your naked soul.
(Emily Dickinson)
```

Poem 2:

```
Shall I compare thee to a summer’s day?
Thou art more lovely and more temperate.
Rough winds do shake the darling buds of May,
And summer’s lease hath all too short a date.
```

(William Shakespeare)

Comment: What an extraordinary question! Surely the essence of writing poetry is to be a free spirit, doing whatever the creative urge tells you to? There are no rules!

Comment: @MichaelKay There are no "rules", but that doesn't mean there aren't publishing conventions. I think it's perfectly reasonable to ask about the conventions of formatting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The visual layout of a poem can sometimes be important to its meaning or interpretation. It's not a particularly common technique so, in a book of poetry, one might expect to find such poems alongside more "standard" left-aligned poems. Some of their value would be lost if all were left-aligned so: no, a book of poetry should not have standard formatting.

By way of example I picked up a collection by my favourite poet, RS Thomas, off the shelf. The first poem, like the majority in the book, is left-aligned:
[image]

But further into the collection there are some with non-standard indents, such as this example which is based on a dialogue between two speakers and uses them to indicate breaks in speech:
[image]

This isn't a particularly good example but it's pertinent because they're in the same book.

It's not a technique that's widely used by canon (i.e. critically acclaimed and frequently studied) poets but one exception is this poem about a wheelbarrow from William Carlos Williams, in which each stanza is formatted to look like a wheelbarrow:

[image]

And outside the canon one can find plenty of very playful examples which would be greatly spoiled by standard formatting:

[image]

Comment: Please consider the examples of the formatting I have added newly to my question. Are they acceptable in the same book? This is purely to accommodate the lines for visual appeal and meaning. Some don't fit visually appealing in the hanging format.

Comment: @Ammu I would say that both the answers you have demonstrated beyond question that the answer is yes, it is acceptable. I don't really understand what it is that you're still unsure of?

Comment: I am unsure because in the poetry books that I have come across, I haven't seen such varied formatting in a single book. It had been either all left aligned or indented in every other line.

Comment: @Ammu OK, well now you know. Varied formatting is fine & you've seen plenty of examples of it. It's far more important to preserve the author's intended formatting than for the text to be "neat". Worth noting that there are examples in novels too, such as House of Leaves and Finnegan's Wake.

Answer (score 5):

There is no "should", except perhaps for a publisher's objections, and poets have been playing with typographic and layout conventions for quite some time.
For a relatively early example, see George Herbert's (1593–1633) [Easter Wings](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/44361/easter-wings) (fist stanza):

[image: stanza consisting of 10 centred lines that become gradually shorter until lines 5 and 6 and then gradually longer again]

In the early 20th century, several poets took this to new extremes. Some examples can be found in [Guillaume Apollinaire's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillaume_Apollinaire) [*Calligrammes*](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Calligrammes), for example, [La Colombe poignardée et le jet d’eau](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Calligrammes/La_Colombe_poignard%C3%A9e_et_le_jet_d%E2%80%99eau):

[image: words and letters arranged on a page so they represent a pigeon with its wings spread out above a fountain]

Not all of Apollinaire's *Calligrammes* go to such extremes. For example [La Nuit d’avril 1915](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Calligrammes/La_Nuit_d%E2%80%99avril_1915) just has some unusual indented lines.

In Dutch literature, [Paul van Ostaijen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_van_Ostaijen) wrote a few poems that took similar liberties with typography and layout as Apollinaire's experiments, for example "BOEM paukeslag":

[image: Poem or text in which font size and boldness appear to be used to represent loudness or emphasis]

Example from Van Ostaijen's *Music hall* (1916):

[image: poem with a few curved lines at the top, a stanza with indented lines and a fine line in which one word runs diagonally downward]

**Conclusion**: There are no "rules" about the types of formatting, typography and indentation that should be used in a volume of poetry. This is a matter of negotiation between a poet and his publisher.

Comment: These are all extreme formatting but they have a reason, especially the  Calligrammes.  I am wondering about simple regular formatting examples of which I have added newly to my questions.

Comment: @Ammu I have added the following conclusion to my answer: "There are no "rules" about the types of formatting, typography and indentation that should be used in a volume of poetry. This is a matter of negotiation between a poet and his publisher." If you can have some of the extreme examples that I have included in my answer, the simpler question of variations in indents should also be negotiable.